# How to call a stored procedure and return just the first result set from within another stored procedure in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server-2019

We are using SQL Server 2019, and have an existing stored procedure which returns two result sets.

I am trying to build a new stored procedure which will call this procedure and store the data from its first result set in a temporary table so it can be used, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Changing the first stored procedure is not an option, and I would prefer not to duplicate it as that would mean maintaining two versions and would almost inevitably lead to problems later on.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: To save going over old ground, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe straight-up T-SQL doesn't really have any means of handling multiple result sets being returned from a stored procedure, in any meaningful way .....

Comment: One solution I've used before - really only suitable for ad-hoc use tbh, is to use `openrowset` which ignores additional result sets

Comment: I give up. I couldn't get openrowset to work so i've resorted to duplicating the stored procedure I was trying to call, but without the code creating the second result set.